# HttpClient execute but hangs, is API called?

Tags: java, freeze, java-http-client

I used JAVA HttpClient to login to an API

Then HttpClient execute in a loop and use this function (`checkZipFile`), after the first time, it hangs at `client.execute(post)`.

```
private String checkZipFile(HttpClient client, File zipFile){
        String errCode = "";
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL_API);
            
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.addTextBody("command", "ImportCustomMaster");
            builder.addTextBody("type", "csvZip");
            builder.addBinaryBody(
              "dataFile", zipFile);
            builder.addTextBody("encoding", "932");
         
            HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
            
            post.setEntity(multipart);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post); //<-- IT HANGS HERE
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + URL_API);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + "dataFile: " + zipFile.getName());
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(result.toString())));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                Node nNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("error").item(0);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    errCode = eElement.getElementsByTagName("code").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("Error Code : " + errCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
        }catch (ConnectException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return errCode;
    }
```

I don't certainly know the reason why, but at least, is the API called and then it sticks because of API or my program?
Is there some tools to investigate that?

Answer (score 1):

The API hangs, not your application.

Try using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or curl in order to check the response time of the API. It may be because of a large file size or a slow internet connection -> try sending a very small file just to check that.

Comment: Thank you, file size is just approx. 1KB. Should I close some response? Till the time it stuck, httpClient just made 2 executions, stuck at the third execution.

Comment: Try with postman then, 3 executions one after the other. They may have throttling in place, but that should return a failed response, not hang. Anyway, if Postman fails, it's something you need to check with them, as there isn't much you can do.